# SQL- Joining tables on common column

Tags: sql-server, join

This query:

```
SELECT CID, count(*) as NumOccurences
FROM Violations
WHERE DateOfViolation BETWEEN (dateadd(day, -30, getdate())) AND getdate()
GROUP BY CID
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

gives the following result:

```
    CID  NumOccurences
    1921    5
    1042    5
    1472    5
    1543    5
    2084    5
    2422    5
```

`NumOccurences` is verified to be correct. Since CID exists in another tables, **I want to tie `CID` to its intersection, a column in said other table `Placement[CID,Intersection,...]`, and display that instead.**

My desired output is:

```
    Intersection        NumOccurences
    Elston and Charles  5
    Diservey and Pkwy   5
    Grand and Chicago   5
    ...
    ...
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT Intersection, count(DateOfViolation) as NumOccurences 
FROM Violations
inner join Placement on Violations.CID = Placement.CID
WHERE DateOfViolation BETWEEN (dateadd(day, -30, getdate())) AND getdate()
GROUP BY Intersection
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

but get this result (not correct):

```
    Intersection            NumOccurences
    CALIFORNIA AND DIVERSEY 90
    BELMONT AND KEDZIE      83
    KOSTNER AND NORTH       82
    STONEY ISLAND AND 79TH  78
    RIDGE AND CLARK         60
    ROOSEVELT AND HALSTED   60
    ROOSEVELT AND KOSTNER   60
```

In fact, I've got no idea what my attempt query is even returning or where it's coming from.

**EDIT**
Running the query

```
SELECT CID, count(*) as num
from Placement
where Intersection = 'BELMONT AND KEDZIE'
group by Intersection, Address, CID
order by Intersection, Address, CID
```

yeilds

```
CID     num
1372    1
1371    1
1373    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    MIN(Placement.Intersection) AS Intersection,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Violation.VID /* Violation ID? */) AS NumOccurences 
FROM Violations INNER JOIN Placement ON Violations.CID = Placement.CID
WHERE DateOfViolation
    BETWEEN cast(dateadd(day, -30, getdate()) as date) AND cast(getdate() as date)
GROUP BY Violations.CID
ORDER BY NumOccurences DESC;
```

Also be careful with that date range. I'm not sure whether you're dealing with `date` or `datetime`.

You might also try:

```
SELECT
    (
    SELECT MIN(Intersection) FROM Placement
    WHERE Placement.CID = Violations.CID
    ) AS Intersection,
    COUNT(*) AS NumOccurences
FROM Violations
WHERE DateOfViolation
    BETWEEN cast(dateadd(day, -30, getdate()) as date) AND cast(getdate() as 
GROUP BY CID
ORDER BY NumOccurences DESC;
```

You may not even need the `MIN()` in that second one.

Answer (score 1):

There would have to be a one-to-one relationship between CIDs and Intersections for you to get the result you are after.

83 is actually a prime number, which would suggest that not only are there multiple entries for the BELMONT and KEDZIE intersection in the Placement table, but also that there is more than one CID corresponding to that intersection.  The same may be true for other intersections

Try this:

```
SELECT Intersection, CID, count(*) as num
from Placement
-- where Intersection = 'BELMONT AND KEDZIE'
group by Intersection, CID
order by Intersection, CID
```

That will show you how many of each (intersection, CID) combination in your Placement table (uncomment the where clause to look at 'Belmont and Kenzie' specifically).  Then re-ask yourself what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, there are at most 2 CID's corresponding to those intersections. CID's are Camera ID's, and one intersection can have at most 2 (one for each direction of traffic). I think I see what the problem is. My query becomes a lot more complicated then (for me atleast). Count the number of violations from BOTH CID's and list them under the same intersection name. Do you mind showing me you're thought process that takes you to the correct solution? **EDIT** Ouch, Belmont and Kezie have 3 CID's (bad data)...Adding the violations from them aswell then?

Comment: Are you able to show me what the result of the query I've posted is with the where clause added?  Just the CID and num columns are fine.

Comment: Added to OP, thank you. This data was pulled from my city's public database. Ave and Avenue should be synonymous

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me that there are only three entries for 'BELMONT and KEDZIE' in your Placement table, if the maximum number of rows per CID in your violations table is 5.  You shouldn't be able to get more than 15 'BELMONT and KEDZIE' rows when you join the two tables.  I don't know if count(DateofViolation) (rather than count(*)) does something funny, but I can't recall why it would

Comment: The maximum number of rows per CID in my violations table is not 5 . In my query above, 5 was the number of times those CID's showed up in the past 30 days. If I increase the span to 60 days, for example, I get 29 as the maximum number. I might be misinterpreting your findings, though.

Comment: and you have definitely pasted the result of the 2nd query in your opening post correctly? (i.e., you definitely included the where clause?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118723/discussion-between-vorpulus-lyphane-and-user3487243).

Comment: Thanks, but totally mystified as to how your answer could have been the correct one.  As far as I can tell, you've effectively just replaced the CID in his original table with *one of* the Placements that contains that CID. Would the questioner still be happy if you changed MIN to MAX, therefore giving a completely different set of results? The results might *look* good but, unless I'm missing something, the results from your query have no meaning and the fact that the answer has been accepted makes me wonder what on Earth the questioner was trying to achieve. Please someone, enlighten me...

Comment: Actually Max might give the same result. Instead, the questioner should take the table given in your answer, group it by placement,and order by count (*) desc and see if they are happy with what they see.

Comment: Finally, I question whether my observation was that great, since there could have been 83 rows for BELMONT AND KEDZIE in the Placement table, all of which having the same CID, and only one row with that CID in the Violations table. ;-)

Comment: This is basically what I was picturing: http://rextester.com/NID77974 In my first query I was just trying to make a minimal change to the original query that would probably work. The second was based more on a hunch about what the data really looked like.

Comment: Thanks for showing me this (I will use that tool in future too). However, if i run it, I see exactly what I was expecting, as described in my comments above. Multiple rows per intersection (you can clearly see that in your rows), none of which have any meaning.  If you disagree, what, in words, does the first row of your table show you? What about the third row (i.e., the other row with B&K intersection)? The query you have described as wrong is the one that's actually right - it shows you the number of violations in that intersection in the given time frame.

Comment: OP wanted violations per camera, the rest is just descriptive. Agreed it really doesn't seem complete without including the camera id or some info to disambiguate. But I guess I can't presume how this is being used.

Comment: That was your interpretation of "Count the number of violations from BOTH CID's and list them under the same intersection name."? (See first comment under my answer).